# How to have the capital letter of every word in a row?

Tags: javascript, html

I’m setting up a new server, and want to support UTF-8 fully in my web application.How to have the capital letter of every word in a row?
When I enter text, I want each word to have a capital letter
example: input: daniel is big king output: Daniel Is Big King.
I don't know what I'm missing
example: input: daniel is big king output: Daniel is big king.
Only the first word has a large initial letter

```js
testfunction = () => {
  var inputtext = document.getElementById('inputtext').value;
  var operation = inputtext.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + inputtext.slice(1);
  console.log(operation);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id='inputtext'>
<button onclick="testfunction()">
Try it
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the css property `text-transform: capitalize;`

```js
testfunction = () => {
  var inputtext = document.getElementById('inputtext').value;
  var operation = inputtext.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + inputtext.slice(1);
  document.getElementById('testview').innerHTML = operation;
}
```

```css
#testview {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id='inputtext'>
<button onclick="testfunction()">
Try it
</button>
<br>
<span id='testview'>
</span>
```

Comment: For display purposes this works, however if OP plans to use that value in JavaScript (store it, pass it, etc), it's worth noting that it will remain unchanged.

Comment: @TylerRoper He can reuse this css property when he want to show it